# Tab Tag in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to write plain text with a Tab character between values in HAML like

```
Name     Age      Address
Paul     23       1115 W Franklin
```

so that when i copy above data in excel spreadsheet it must copied to different columns like

```
Paul copied to column A, 23 copied to column B and so on...
```

so how to insert tab between values?

Comment: Both of the supplied answers provide a solution to the question you asked. You should accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure if this is the right way to accomplished above, but one of my colleague answered this and its working absolutely fine

To display data tab separated we need to render data in a textarea like this

```
     %textarea{:cols => 40, :rows=>5, :readonly => "readonly"}= "#{@account.Name}\t#{@account.Number}\t#{@account.Address}\n"
```

and when it is copied, it goes to different columns in spreadsheet

Hope this help to others too.....

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be using :plain block

```
:plain
  Name     Age      Address
  Paul     23       1115 W Franklin
```

Comment: :plain will add tab between values?

Comment: @AnilD Place an actual tab character, ASCII value 0x09, in your source text. Just because it looks like whitespace in your source code, and just because it doesn't align properly in HTML, does not mean that it will not copy as a tab for Excel.

Comment: Will you please tell me how to include 0x09 in HAML?

Comment: @AnilD Exactly like either of these answers. Look: `Haml::Engine.new(":plain\n  foo\tbar").render #=> "foo\tbar\n"` and `Haml::Engine.new("%p foo\tbar").render #=> "<p>foo\tbar</p>\n"` and `Haml::Engine.new('%p= "foo\tbar"').render #=> "<p>foo\tbar</p>\n"`. Set your text editor to use real tab characters, and _just press the tab key_.

Comment: @Phrogz , thanks for you reply, but i m not getting how to accomplish it, i m new to HAML, i m using Aptana studio as editor, not getting where to change text editor settings, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
= "Name\tAge\tAddress\n"
= "Paul\t23 \t1115 W Franklin\n"
```

or

```
= "Name\tAge\tAddress\n"
= "#{name}\t#{age} \t#{address}\n"
```

Comment: \t doesn't add tab space between words, just add a single space
need to add tab space so when copied to excel will goes to different columns

Comment: I think you are confusing your web browser display needs with your Excel needs. You've asked for help with what gets copied, but it sounds like you may have unspoken requirements for what is displayed.

Comment: @Phrogz , i just need to display data like "Paul 23 1115 W Franklin",
the main thing is when this data is copied should go to separate columns, using \t between values doesn't do same